# Meteor OAuth Exception while invoking method 'login'

Tags: exception, authentication, oauth, meteor

While trying to login using the Meteor packages *accounts-facebook* and *accounts-google*, I'm getting an OAuth handler exception. Packages ***accounts-twitter*** appears to work fine and logs in perfectly. I haven't written any code, this is right out of the box using the *accounts-ui* package

The front end simply says "Internal Server Error" in red text, and the Meteor stack trace is the following:

```
Exception in oauth request handler [Error: failed]
Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: failed
at Request.Meteor.http.call [as _callback] (app/packages/http/httpcall_server.js:117:19)
at Request.init.self.callback (/usr/lib64/meteor/lib/node_modules/request/main.js:122:22)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib64/meteor/lib/node_modules/request/main.js:654:16)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:123:20)
at IncomingMessage.Request.start.self.req.self.httpModule.request.buffer (/usr/lib64/meteor/lib/node_modules/request/main.js:616:14)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:123:20)
at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:23)
at CleartextStream.socketOnData (http.js:1366:20)
```

I'm running the Meteor app on my own infrastructure with a working domain name. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it turned out my service was not configured correctly, specifically I had the wrong Facebook app secret.  Go into your mongo shell and check your meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration to ensure it's set up correctly.
Start up Meteor, then go into the mongo shell via `meteor mongo`
Then type 'db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.find()' to show the documents in that collection.  Now check your Facebook document to ensure it matches the app you created on Facebook exactly.

I did this and everything worked immediately.

Comment: This didn't help me, it all matches up there.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for that. Our error reporting in these cases sucked. A fix is coming out in the soon-to-be-released Meteor 0.6.2.